# How to Sync Contact From Android to Web Server

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

**Which Methods Is best for Sync From Android to Web Server if possible to give me example**

Comment: what exactly is a problem for you? show what you have tried, and what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was storing contacts from phone in my database and then sending the contacts to the server in chunks and keeping status of contacts. After that only the updated contacts are sent to server which are not synced. 
For udated contacts you can use observer or query provider on the basis of timestamp.